# Python/Discord - Storage for large amount of data

Tags: python, discord

I have a command that will be reading through a large amount of messages in a channel, then counting occurrences of a certain userTag.

What would be the best and fastest type of storage to do this, would it be writing and reading txt file?

Essentially the command will be ,chk *user*
This will search through a designated channel for all times that user has been mentioned, if the user is mentioned it will var +=1

It is also checking with an if statement to see if the author of the @usermention has already been added to the count, to avoid adding the same author more than once.

OR is there anyway to use .find or a similar way to search through discord history without looping through every message in that channel?

Comment: How much data?  Discord channels are just text, you're not going to build gigabytes.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have a for loop going through the message history of a channel, probably up to maybe 10k messages? Right now, I have it going through and saving the mention author to a dict, but it takes over a min to finish